# Dynamic value changing from server response compare to replace in the JMeter script

Tags: jmeter

Few of the token values are changing compare to response to replaced in the script. please let me know how to over come this issue

1st value

Recorded Server response in JMeter recording log

VI1js8eNsTKaakYaEsdhPPg+nlPY2SL6/0RoyxBL1BE=

Replaced value in the JMeter script

VI1js8eNsTKaakYaEsdhPPg%2BnlPY2SL6%2F0RoyxBL1BE%3D

2nd value

Server response

C/K6QoR6Qjk/pLQAyvQ5FiRXFK9BAxeRJAEDJ+BGA+w=

Replaced value in the JMeter script

C%2FK6QoR6Qjk%2FpLQAyvQ5FiRXFK9BAxeRJAEDJ%2BBGA%2Bw%3D

Please hlep to to over come this issue.

Thanks
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is some form of encryption/decryption logic which is applied to certain request parameters, it's not possible to guess the algorithm so if you don't know it you need to ask around.

Once you will know what exact encryption algorithm is being applied - you should be able to perform the same either using [__digest()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) or [__groovy()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) functions